# Rails 4 sql query interpretation with mysql or sqlite3

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm using sqlite in development and mysql in production.

One the same SQL query works fine in the development mode and gives an error when executing in the production.

In sqlite (works!):

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."id" = ? OR "events"."deadline" BETWEEN '2015-01-28 22:56:05.651383' AND '2016-01-28 22:56:05.651385'
```

In mysql (doesn't work):

```
SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (`events`.`id` =  OR `events`.`deadline` BETWEEN '2015-01-28 22:24:10.837686' AND '2016-01-28 22:24:10.837690')
```

The error message:

```
ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR `events`.`deadline` BETWEEN '2015-01-28 22:24:10.837686' AND '2016-01-28 22:2' at line 1: SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (`events`.`id` =  OR `events`.`deadline` BETWEEN '2015-01-28 22:24:10.837686' AND '2016-01-28 22:24:10.837690')
```

Controller action code

```
def edit
  query = Event.unscoped.where( deadline: (Time.now)..(Time.now + 1.year), id: @booking.event_id )
  @events = Event.where(query.where_values.inject(:or))
end
```

Mysql misses "?" sign and I don't understand why. Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you should be using the same DB in dev that you're using in production.

Secondly, this is not a reliable way to do `OR` queries, in fact it no longer works in Rails 4.2 thanks to the Adequate Record work.

If you want to do `OR`s reliably, then use Arel, ie.:

```
e = Event.arel_table
@events = Event.where(e[:id].eq(@booking.event_id).or(e[:deadline].in(Time.now..Time.now + 1.year)))
```

See more in this excellent article: http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/03/just-enough-arel.html